# Jump to the next word in insert mode

Tags: vim

Is there a way to jump to the next word when in the insert mode. Something similar to `w` when in non-insert mode or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> in windows?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's a very useful table of insert mode motions at [`:h ins-special-special`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-special).

```
<S-Left>    cursor one word back (like "b" command)
<C-Left>    cursor one word back (like "b" command)
<S-Right>   cursor one word forward (like "w" command)
<C-Right>   cursor one word forward (like "w" command)
```

You'll find that Shift-Left/Right and Ctrl-Left/Right will do the trick.

Ctrl/Shift with cursor keys isn't guaranteed to work flawlessly in all terminals, however. You can avoid any problems entirely by using a mapping. Here's one right on to the home row:

```
:inoremap <C-H> <C-\><C-O>b
:inoremap <C-L> <C-\><C-O>w
```

Now use `CTRL-H` and `CTRL-L` to move by word in insert mode.

***However,*** please be aware that many Vimmers prefer not to move at all in insert mode. That's because once you have moved in insert mode, the `.` command loses its utility, as does [`CTRL-A`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-A) and maybe some other commands.

For me, the Vim way of jumping to the next word in insert mode is `<C-[>wi` and it's become completely automatic.

Comment: Note that <C-H> is usually your backspace key so you might loose the ability to backspace something. (This is however terminal dependent)

Answer (score 24):

With `<CTRL-O>`, you can execute one command without exiting insert mode.

So you can try `<CTRL-O>w`, `<CTRL-O>3w`, etc.

Comment: The best solution so far for the problem. Kudos!

Answer (score 10):

You can move one word forwards/backwards in Insert mode by holding down either Shift or Control and pressing the right or left arrow key.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using the arrow keys?

Comment: It's working in a shell but not in the vim for me so I'm looking for the way how to configure it.